# How do i return a single Task object when the async code has multiple that all need to be awaited?

Tags: .net, async-await

I want to return a single `await`-able Task from my method that launches several async executions.  How can I do this?

```
public async Task DoThingsAsync() {
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(DoAsync());
    tasks.Add(DoAsync());
    tasks.Add(DoSomethingElseAsync());

    return WHAT_CAN_GO_HERE(tasks);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `async` from your method and return the result of [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public Task DoThingsAsync() {
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(DoAsync());
    tasks.Add(DoAsync());
    tasks.Add(DoSomethingElseAsync());

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

If there are actually `await`s hiding in your real code, you may instead stay `async` and `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` inside this method. You then of course just `return;` rather than returning anything, because that's what `async Task` (not `Task<T>`) methods do.

Comment: When would this block to require completion of all the tasks?  Before `return`, or when the caller `await`s?

Comment: `Task`s represent work that's either in progress or already finished (ignoring cold `Task`s). When you need them to be finished, that's when you `await` them and you may either "block" (but of course, not blocking the thread, just your logical progress) or continue working if (happily) they'd already finished.

Comment: Is it correct or incorrect use the `Async` suffix on the method name in this case?

Comment: Async suffix is still correct here. The method is considered async because it returns some sort of Task. The async keyword is not relevant outside of the method's implementation.